# Using field Calculator for time in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, time

I have a  new field in a shapefile with the property "Date". I want to fill it with "9:00:00 AM". I tried several ways of using field calculator, but it gives date instead of time. How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For shapefiles, the time portion is truncated from the datetime value. So you should work inside a geodatabase if you need the time. If you really need to work in a shapefile, I suggest that you try it within a text field